# Combining shape and fill aesthetics in a single legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I currently have a plot with two levels for 'shape' ('2 deg C' represented by a square and '5 deg C' represented by a circle) and two levels for 'fill' ('high food' represented with gray fill and 'low food' represented with white fill). I would like to add a single legend that includes the four possible combinations of these aesthetics: 2 deg C HF, 2 deg C LF, 5 deg C HF, and 5 deg C LF represented as a gray-filled square, white-filled square, gray-filled circle, white-filled circle, respectively.

Here is my current code:

```
tank_2and5_cumulative_mort_summary$Species <- factor(tank_2and5_cumulative_mort_summary$Species, levels = c(1,2), labels = c("Later Stage Arctic Cod", "Later Stage Walleye Pollock"))
#Error bars
error_bars <- aes(ymax = mean + se, ymin = mean - se)
ggplot(tank_2and5_cumulative_mort_summary, aes(Day, mean, shape = factor(Target_Temp),fill=factor(Feeding))) +
  geom_point(stat = "identity",size=3.5) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=50,linetype="dashed") +
  annotate("text", x=25, y=46, label='italic(M[50])', size=6, parse=TRUE) +
  annotate("text", x=-0.2, y=100, label=c('bold(A.)','bold(B.)'), size=6, parse=TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100)) + 
  scale_shape_manual(name="Temperature (ºC)",labels=c("2 ºC","5 ºC"),values=c(22,21)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Food Ration",labels=c("High Food","Low Food"),values=c("gray30","white")) +
  xlab("Day of Experiment") +
  ylab(bquote(bold('Cumulative mortality (% '~ day^-1*')'))) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21)), shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "gray30"))) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 16, color='black'), axis.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(size = 16), legend.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"), strip.text.x = element_text(size=16,face="bold"), plot.title = element_text(size = 18, face = "bold", hjust=0.5), strip.background = element_rect(color="white",fill = "white")) + 
  facet_wrap(~Species,nrow=2,scales='free_x')
```

Here is an image of my current plot with separate shape and fill legends:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUr0m.png)

Here is a reproducible example:

```
    structure(list(Target_Temp = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L
), Day = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L), Feeding = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Species = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Later Stage Arctic Cod", "Later Stage Walleye Pollock"
), class = "factor"), N = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    mean = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 6.316910603, 13.2880844666667, 6.10170531233333, 
    14.5063518366667, 10.804416043, 18.2051282033333, 14.6413527966667, 
    16.8423777966667, 20.9915481366667, 22.3730517833333, 28.2392753433333, 
    24.7158934, 22.8209532966667, 23.2277526366667, 37.4549135066667, 
    30.1798536333333, 27.3714468933333, 24.8667672166667, 47.22038196, 
    34.7369511166667, 30.03811356, 27.8667672166667, 49.8870486266667, 
    38.4036177833333, 35.6859754033333, 31.2151835133333, 54.24806772, 
    40.9771471966667, 38.8871481233333, 33.6033182533333, 56.06624954, 
    43.7091273133333, 42.08832085, 35.2071392666667, 59.8212080333333, 
    46.51463684, 43.9919375166667, 40.15937657, 60.4622336733333, 
    47.8909831533333, 44.6092214666667, 42.58270488, 61.1032593166667, 
    48.30764982, 45.8437893666667, 45.8959276, 61.1032593166667, 
    51.87296327, 46.4610733166667, 49.60130719, 61.6880546366667, 
    54.5200220933333, 48.9189857766667, 52.4519859233333, 62.3290802766667, 
    60.1158519733333, 49.5992578866667, 59.96832579, 66.0840387666667, 
    63.2852112666667, 49.5992578866667, 62.0698843633333, 66.72506441, 
    64.6615575833333, 49.5992578866667, 63.7088989433333, 67.36609005, 
    65.9643744833333, 49.5992578866667, 67.4494720966667, 69.1417413, 
    67.3614333066667, 50.2795299933333, 68.73152338, 69.7478019066667, 
    68.8113090333333, 50.2795299933333, 69.9783810966667, 70.3325972266667, 
    70.7513808333333, NaN, 72.0799396666667, NaN, 74.5372825166667, 
    NaN, 72.5072900966667, NaN, 74.9539491833333, NaN, 72.9346405233333, 
    NaN, 75.7872825166667, NaN, 74.5736551, NaN, 77.09009942, 
    NaN, 75.39316239, NaN, 77.09009942, NaN, 75.39316239, NaN, 
    77.09009942, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.613756614, 2.88065843633333, 14.9853801146667, 
    4.88582018166667, 21.507936508, 4.938271605, 25.7901698666667, 
    7.72895743633333, 32.4338624333333, 7.40740740733333, 35.9335839566667, 
    11.7874222853333, 36.7460317466667, 9.46502057433333, 43.9049011433333, 
    14.2527498803333, 37.2751322766667, 12.3456790133333, 47.3997493733333, 
    17.8802008603333, 38.60846561, 14.01234568, 47.7330827066667, 
    18.8802008603333, 42.41798942, 18.1275720133333, 47.7330827066667, 
    26.9176231466667, 44.5873015866667, 25.5349794233333, 51.2174881633333, 
    32.5961262566667, 48.9523809533333, 29.23868313, 53.5775549966667, 
    37.8352462933333, 50.0634920633333, 31.2962962966667, 54.16235032, 
    41.06456241, 52.78835979, 35.4115226333333, 55.3319409633333, 
    43.9017216633333, 55.5132275166667, 40.3497942366667, 56.4458368133333, 
    47.5722142533333, 56.0423280433333, 43.2304526766667, 61.70899471, 
    48.80188905, 56.5714285733333, 47.3456790133333, 62.8890281233333, 
    52.0557149666667, 59.9047619033333, 50.6378600833333, 65.1168198266667, 
    54.0308464866667, 63.2380952366667, 53.1069958833333, 67.3550543033333, 
    58.56934481, 65.3544973533333, 57.6337448566667, 69.00849346, 
    59.81934481, 68.60846561, 61.7489711933333, 69.6037315533333, 
    61.4268292666667, 72.4444444466667, 66.6872428, 69.6037315533333, 
    63.87183166, NaN, 72.0370370333333, NaN, 66.2923242466667, 
    NaN, 76.56378601, NaN, 66.69882831, NaN, 77.3868312766667, 
    NaN, 67.9039933033333, NaN, 80.26748971, NaN, 69.1539933033333, 
    NaN, 83.1481481466667, NaN, 71.9666427566667, NaN, 84.38271605, 
    NaN, 72.3833094233333, NaN, 85.2057613166667, NaN, 75.2162840733333
    ), sd = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.874946380374836, 3.21917779550928, 
    1.04522569941729, 6.16803477118, 1.49556920069362, 4.74878440292428, 
    3.12246139797711, 7.10523995814722, 3.9765349552553, 3.97438997786273, 
    7.74317862106826, 9.52930224175235, 3.75711247762319, 3.85501596227901, 
    9.72189321741946, 10.5131247007767, 6.31929872007114, 2.71075316746443, 
    10.5220768461455, 12.718286386903, 6.68623915517232, 3.04413120198825, 
    11.0986529430163, 13.2032228288885, 5.11752403494854, 2.01510177097222, 
    13.5905284444751, 10.1736126920253, 4.83940555870643, 4.78902174062332, 
    14.9172021670437, 11.2248102126018, 4.85706196771701, 6.44932982135379, 
    16.8824360091378, 12.654988628294, 4.95087415865093, 7.25754637594045, 
    17.6100519005675, 12.7174062928319, 4.05937578271578, 9.37022989516587, 
    18.3759814337981, 12.1789583794603, 2.69666384909201, 9.68532467289556, 
    18.3759814337981, 12.34539641926, 2.46942974676307, 11.1059883712979, 
    17.3990190625204, 9.94929987930963, 3.09095660399878, 12.835743712853, 
    18.2106975912416, 8.8711946391549, 3.31401725549042, 13.2082642443798, 
    20.8946175996798, 8.84238080778593, 3.31401725549042, 13.43915519733, 
    21.8065585516555, 8.80175008781921, 3.31401725549042, 13.8906473958853, 
    22.7361480934535, 9.63856327060737, 3.31401725549042, 12.1627388108535, 
    20.9850835175516, 8.17075309364404, 3.89718216741624, 10.8838675082689, 
    21.0601993519721, 7.24898490800861, 3.89718216741624, 10.1634650890434, 
    20.1426607899407, 5.88285387324051, NA, 11.0022775157161, 
    NA, 6.02674810623141, NA, 10.2994184473947, NA, 5.6387873628524, 
    NA, 9.60217166167771, NA, 5.0861953657389, NA, 9.3624429585716, 
    NA, 5.62081253377385, NA, 9.32210276006274, NA, 5.62081253377385, 
    NA, 9.32210276006274, NA, 5.62081253377385, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.4130060152249, 
    1.42555622052779, 5.10722096742217, 1.36031076674339, 10.411960387716, 
    1.234567901, 7.1312471736126, 3.23840241134935, 10.353214405732, 
    2.13833433050301, 7.74380072384587, 5.70125345431274, 8.21457326458282, 
    4.6739986359138, 10.3884569723183, 7.67596804199393, 7.43932089721875, 
    3.26635964569273, 13.4185821185945, 10.1244770438109, 7.4208060976192, 
    3.67036435135213, 13.260809662063, 10.1244770438109, 5.97174276271196, 
    4.21058850347649, 13.260809662063, 10.9427025641944, 5.15965803190317, 
    2.35282645412571, 14.6336833418929, 7.49002889199581, 4.56423044331738, 
    2.3528264490447, 15.4797281897624, 8.69066334506041, 5.50001717565586, 
    1.75842518551224, 14.9532265351562, 8.29501898064852, 5.37158742704296, 
    5.30175167809815, 14.0608933607649, 7.58558969679427, 6.43212391215584, 
    4.32134625378667, 13.1171116487744, 7.74815703108229, 5.81278279331372, 
    6.08981616177995, 12.9319432355214, 6.89546536178341, 5.28056377247449, 
    6.99235325954397, 13.940366472244, 6.8264498267838, 8.36348287376577, 
    8.09108652040442, 12.9288073935427, 6.86861633789757, 10.5309176584841, 
    8.09108652040442, 12.1197965702862, 9.9697393650369, 7.85828648432097, 
    6.39978296241699, 10.8954843008132, 11.8879417886052, 7.85548055882995, 
    8.96758998228674, 11.5612455041564, 11.8655152508709, 7.42617991430518, 
    7.80340997976923, 11.5612455041564, 11.3756358937427, NA, 
    5.95526430951861, NA, 10.1912263707779, NA, 5.70205113907211, 
    NA, 9.65109867906726, NA, 5.24684580067051, NA, 8.46380371035579, 
    NA, 4.53979228404506, NA, 10.5532458684488, NA, 3.8348588411187, 
    NA, 9.22606458800838, NA, 3.83485884477264, NA, 9.92447971782915, 
    NA, 3.64396960245818, NA, 11.0144885987119), se = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.505150528235901, 1.85859316680655, 0.603461338922486, 
    3.56111653551174, 0.863467280612173, 2.74171195335183, 1.8027539286563, 
    4.10221220249319, 2.29585352685861, 2.2946151235836, 4.47052626125712, 
    5.50174521446502, 2.16916990033145, 2.22569450355209, 5.61293766610992, 
    6.06975537601754, 3.64844881712273, 1.56505407094222, 6.07492389955605, 
    7.34290606910919, 3.86030197610495, 1.75752996891646, 6.40781026429271, 
    7.62288425442937, 2.95460387916192, 1.1634195499153, 7.84649525584698, 
    5.87373802637182, 2.79403210203693, 2.76494299110384, 8.61245068669875, 
    6.48064719784809, 2.80422603453211, 3.72352230845129, 9.74707897445231, 
    7.30636109113718, 2.85838852822108, 4.19014635380541, 10.1671682052359, 
    7.34239794656033, 2.34368170089281, 5.4099047523427, 10.6093778274269, 
    7.03152489883066, 1.5569195991872, 5.59182480708517, 10.6093778274269, 
    7.12761794591242, 1.42572592903853, 6.41204537578567, 10.0453283393816, 
    5.74423096356773, 1.78456462737215, 7.41072008786474, 10.5139511564342, 
    5.12178661294965, 1.91334875455646, 7.62579491702037, 12.0635130957894, 
    5.10515093965239, 1.91334875455646, 7.75909987085965, 12.5900224498976, 
    5.08169278254223, 1.91334875455646, 8.01976901323257, 13.1267212220906, 
    5.56482709888641, 1.91334875455646, 7.02216052652937, 12.1157436178252, 
    4.71738649809735, 2.25003917343878, 6.28380383572325, 12.1591117650483, 
    4.18520338799031, 2.25003917343878, 5.86787930505854, 11.6293706292676, 
    3.39646726731864, NA, 6.35216788539765, NA, 3.47954464147077, 
    NA, 5.94637201309994, NA, 3.25555540184589, NA, 5.54381639367462, 
    NA, 2.93651626356038, NA, 5.40540896240383, NA, 3.24517762943875, 
    NA, 5.38211853793558, NA, 3.24517762943875, NA, 5.38211853793558, 
    NA, 3.24517762943875, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.97049994163591, 0.823045267666667, 
    2.94865540035209, 0.785375787360845, 6.01134813263954, 0.712778109975221, 
    4.11722747534299, 1.86969250393688, 5.9774311241273, 1.23456790133333, 
    4.47088543246323, 3.29162021656575, 4.74268608558479, 2.69853437063678, 
    5.99777842943283, 4.43172221533616, 4.29509392259725, 1.88583362071083, 
    7.74722199831363, 5.84536954664842, 4.28440439806446, 2.11908584627716, 
    7.65613202806447, 5.84536954664842, 3.44778729158295, 2.4309844059289, 
    7.65613202806447, 6.31777227109963, 2.97892995364571, 1.35840498664595, 
    8.44876101667761, 4.32437019703186, 2.63515967509278, 1.35840498371243, 
    8.93722523734159, 5.01755682170704, 3.17543639691247, 1.01522725420531, 
    8.63324936532588, 4.78913144141048, 3.10128744697886, 3.06096775852652, 
    8.11806056688424, 4.37954225340622, 3.7135884721442, 2.49493042288532, 
    7.57316794141026, 4.47340054761885, 3.3560117104605, 3.51595700031899, 
    7.46626090817327, 3.98109878281339, 3.04873491551114, 4.03703703666667, 
    8.0484743353521, 3.9412526451031, 4.82865908853149, 4.67139098059205, 
    7.46445042896271, 3.96559749164542, 6.08002814493961, 4.67139098059204, 
    6.99736781237826, 5.75603170615446, 4.53698381709191, 3.69491641610663, 
    6.29051079402581, 6.86350639176183, 4.53536381525435, 5.17744049025544, 
    6.67488820399202, 6.85055842416392, 4.28750697257469, 4.50530085241678, 
    6.67488820399202, 6.56772644545552, NA, 3.43827345219594, 
    NA, 5.88390728854103, NA, 3.2920807600763, NA, 5.57206442033513, 
    NA, 3.02926783541358, NA, 4.88657935054207, NA, 2.6210502972584, 
    NA, 6.09291934297324, NA, 2.2140567842241, NA, 5.32667087344751, 
    NA, 2.2140567863337, NA, 5.72990103665564, NA, 2.10384683089804, 
    NA, 6.35921795745238)), .Names = c("Target_Temp", "Day", 
"Feeding", "Species", "N", "mean", "sd", "se"), row.names = c(NA, 
-216L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888083/how-to-create-a-legend-with-both-color-and-shape)

Comment: Yeah, I've studied up on those solutions but haven't been able to apply them to my own dataset. Any further explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to mirror answers to either of the links I gave.  What have you tried that has failed?  Seems like you should start be making a single combined variable out of the two you are currently using and go from there.