# Limit the color variation in R using scale_color_grey

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

Before I start, allow me to explain my graph: I have two Genotypes (*WTB* and **whd**) and each have two conditions (**0** and **7**), so I have four lines.

Now, I want to make a plot where each variable and its condition is the same color. Anything with **whd** will be **black** and anything with *WTB* will be *grey*.

I managed to make the graph with the solid/dashed lines correctly, however, I am having trouble with the coloring. I can only make it so that there is a grey gradient. Are there any parameters for `scale_color_grey` to help me with this?

This is my code (I took out parts of it for easier read):

```
ggplot(data=df4, aes(x=Day, y=Remain, group=Condition, shape=Condition, colour=Condition) + 
theme_bw() +
geom_line(aes(linetype=Condition), size=1) +
geom_point(size=0, fill="#FFFFFF") +
scale_linetype_manual(name="Genotype",
values=c("solid", "dashed", "solid", "dashed")) +
scale_shape_manual(name="Genotype", values=c(1,19,1,19)) +
scale_color_grey(name="Genotype")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code should produce the plot you want. However, without your exact dataset, I had to generate simulated data.

```
## Generate dummy data and load library
library(ggplot2)
df4 = data.frame(Remain = rep(0:1, times = 4),
      Day = rep(1:4, each = 2),
      Genotype = rep(c("wtb", "whd"), each = 4),
      Condition = rep(c("0", "7"), times = 4 ))
```

Next, I created a grouping variable:

```
df4$both = paste0(df4$Genotype, df4$Condition)
```

And last, I plotted and saved the figure:

```
example <-  ggplot(data=df4, aes(x=Day, y=Remain, 
                group=both, 
                color = Genotype,
                linetype = Condition)) + 
                geom_line() +
                scale_color_manual(values = c("grey50", "black")) +
                scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dashed")) +
                theme_bw()

ggsave("example.jpg", example)
```

[image]

From your code, it was not apparent why you included the `geom_point`. Also, if you only want one sub-legend, rather than two, this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410908/creating-a-ggplot-legend-with-both-color-and-shape) provides details on how to do that.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you so much! I didn't know about grouping variables, it works so nicely. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. `ggplot` can be trick to work with, but can do lot. As a heads up, mixing the `shape`, `color`, `alpha`, `fill`, etc. parameters with `facets` gives you lots of options for plotting, but can be quirky at times as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll look into those.