# Creating a ggplot legend with color and linetype based on two variables

Tags: ggplot2, legend

In [Creating a ggplot legend with both color and shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410908/creating-a-ggplot-legend-with-both-color-and-shape) there is way how to combine shape and color but based on one variable. I wonder if this is possible if the variable is splitted into two variables.

Hier is a test data:

```
(x <- data.frame(time =rep(1:5,4)
                , sex = rep(c("m","f"), each=5)
                , val_type = rep(c("obs","fit"),each=10)
                , val = rep(1:4,each=5)*rep(1:5,4)
                )
)
```

To show how I want have the legend I combine the two variables:

```
x$sv <- paste(x$sex,x$val_type,sep='-')
```

Here is the ggplot with one variable:

```
ggplot(data=x, aes(x=time, y=val, linetype=sv, col=sv)) +
       geom_line() +
       scale_colour_manual(name = ""
                           , values=c("red","red","blue","blue")
                           , labels=c("Female fitted","Female observed"
                                     ,"Male fitted","Male observed")
                           ) +
       scale_linetype_manual(name = ""
                           , values=c(1,2,1,2)
                           , labels=c("Female fitted","Female observed"
                                     ,"Male fitted","Male observed")
                           )
```

and here is the plot:

[image]

I would like to have the same legend but using the two variables separately

```
ggplot(data=x, aes(x=time, y=val, linetype=val_type, col=sex)) +
       geom_line()
```

Is it possible? The reason I would like not to use a combined variable is that I don't want to create variables I don't need for analysis. Another reason is to see how legend can be customized manually.
Thanks for help.

Comment: It is quite common and frequently necessary to create a data frame just for a single plot, especially for complicated plots. I don't see that as an issue. But it is a good question anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see creating a new variable as a major issue (especially if you would use pipes). But, yes, it's possible by using the `interaction` function and using your manual scale definitions.

```
ggplot(data = x, 
       aes(x = time, 
           y = val, 
           linetype = interaction(val_type, sex),
           col = interaction(val_type, sex))) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(name = ""
                      , values=c("red","red","blue","blue")
                      , labels=c("Female fitted","Female observed"
                                 ,"Male fitted","Male observed")
  ) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = ""
                        , values=c(1,2,1,2)
                        , labels=c("Female fitted","Female observed"
                                   ,"Male fitted","Male observed")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! ggplot constantly surprise me with new commands/parameter/functions like for example `interaction`.

Comment: (`interaction` is from base!)