# How can I combine two unequal length legend into a single legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two unequal length legend of colour and shape, how can I merge them into a single legend?

```
x<-rep(1:5,6)
y<-c(1:30)
group1<-rep(c("C1","C2","C3"),10)
group2<-rep(c("a","b"),each=15)
df<-data.frame(x,y,group1,group2)
ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_point(aes(colour=group1,shape=group2),size=3)
```

Here is my plot:

[image: Here is my plot]

I just want a single legend shown in the plot, how can I do this?

Comment: This answer should put you on the right track: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12411595/3330437

Comment: Thanks! I searched this answer  and tried before asking, but in his case it is a 2×2 combinantion, I want a 2×3 combination legend, do you have any solution ?

Comment: The principle is the same. Create a third group variable for putting in your dataframe with `group3 <- paste(group1, group2)`. Then set `aes(colour = group3, shape = group3)` in your `geom`. Use `scale_****_manual` as in the example to set repeating values so you have vectors of 3 colors two times and 2 shapes 3 times.

Comment: WOW! I got it! Thank you very much!!!