# How can I combine legends for color and linetype into a single legend in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble making a combined legend to show all four options for a plot that combines linetype and color scales. I have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410908/combine-legends-for-color-and-shape-into-a-single-legend) but, as you will discover upon running my plotting code, this does not seem to work - I get the classification correct but cannot make all four elements of the legend print. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
structure(list(Ocean.Regions = c("South Pacific", "South Pacific", 
"South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", 
"South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", 
"South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", 
"South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", 
"South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", 
"South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", 
"South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", 
"South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", 
"South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", 
"South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", "South Pacific", 
"South Pacific", "South Pacific"), binned_alt = c(0, 0, 1000, 
1000, 2000, 2000, 3000, 3000, 4000, 4000, 5000, 5000, 6000, 6000, 
7000, 7000, 8000, 8000, 9000, 9000, 10000, 10000, 11000, 11000, 
12000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 4000, 5000, 7000, 
8000, 8000, 9000, 9000, 10000, 10000, 11000, 11000, 12000), Meteorological_Season_Factor = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Winter", 
"Fall", "Summer", "Spring"), class = "factor"), Species = c("MEK", 
"MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", 
"MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", 
"MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", 
"MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", 
"MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK", "MEK"), `25%` = c(10.25, 
23.95, 6.775, 12.45, 4.65, 5.675, 3.3, 5.5, 4.5, 5.275, 4.6, 
0.348456848923605, 4.35, 0.524861878453039, 3.475, 0.289655172413793, 
0.376811594202899, 0.289655172413793, 0.688259109311741, 0.524861878453039, 
4.15, 0.524861878453039, 0.524861878453039, 0.688259109311741, 
0.688259109311741, 13.4, 22.7, 12.45, 5.92241379310345, 5.4, 
1.84364640883978, 5.2, 2.61724137931034, 5.9, 0.289655172413793, 
0.289655172413793, 0.376811594202899, 11.1, 0.524861878453039, 
10.1, 0.524861878453039, 0.524861878453039, 0.688259109311741, 
0.688259109311741), `50%` = c(13.4, 28.45, 10.7, 17, 8.4, 9.85, 
5.9, 7.25, 5.9, 5.65, 7.15, 1.01243093922652, 6, 0.524861878453039, 
4.75, 0.524861878453039, 2.8, 0.289655172413793, 3.5, 0.524861878453039, 
7.5, 0.524861878453039, 0.524861878453039, 0.688259109311741, 
0.688259109311741, 14.2, 28.4, 17, 10.75, 6.5, 3.16243093922652, 
5.2, 4.9448275862069, 5.9, 0.289655172413793, 0.289655172413793, 
0.376811594202899, 11.1, 0.524861878453039, 10.3, 0.524861878453039, 
0.524861878453039, 0.688259109311741, 0.688259109311741), `75%` = c(16, 
33.9, 17.85, 19.1, 10.15, 16.2, 12.325, 10.3, 9.05, 7.175, 7.425, 
3.775, 7.6, 0.524861878453039, 5.875, 0.524861878453039, 5, 0.524861878453039, 
9, 0.524861878453039, 9.675, 1.31864640883978, 0.524861878453039, 
1.69412955465587, 0.688259109311741, 14.5, 34.2, 19.1, 16.15, 
13.2, 4.48121546961326, 5.2, 7.27241379310345, 5.9, 0.289655172413793, 
0.407258525433416, 0.376811594202899, 11.1, 0.524861878453039, 
10.5, 2.11243093922652, 0.524861878453039, 0.688259109311741, 
0.688259109311741), Treatment = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Clean Marine", "All Data"
), class = "factor")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -44L))
```

And here's the plot code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)

SOtestplot <- test %>%
  filter(Species == "MEK", binned_alt <= 8000) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = binned_alt/1000, x = `50%`, col = Meteorological_Season_Factor, linetype = Treatment)) +
  geom_path(size = 1.2) + 
  theme_tufte(base_size = 22) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin =`25%`, xmax = `75%`), height = 0) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1.5),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "black")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Treatment & Season",
                     values = c("cornflowerblue", "goldenrod3", "cornflowerblue", "goldenrod3"),
                     labels = c("Summer Clean Marine",
                                "Winter Clean Marine",
                                "Summer All Data",
                                "Winter All Data")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Treatment & Season",
                        values = c( "solid", "dashed", "solid", "dashed"),
                        labels = c("Summer Clean Marine",
                                   "Winter Clean Marine",
                                   "Summer All Data",
                                   "Winter All Data")) +
  xlab("MEK (ppt)") +
  ylab("Altitude (km)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Make a hash of the two fields you're using (`mutate(hybrid = paste(Meteorological_Season_Factor, Treatment))`), and then use that for both color and line type (`aes(...col = hybrid, linetype = hybrid)`), and then use named vectors for your values in both `scale` functions.

Is that what you're looking for? (P.S. I believe I used the labels and values you used in the order in which you used them... maybe that was the only problem is that you'd transposed a couple of them!)

```r
SOtestplot <- test %>%
  mutate(hybrid = paste(Meteorological_Season_Factor, Treatment)) %>% 
  filter(Species == "MEK", binned_alt <= 8000) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = binned_alt/1000, x = `50%`, col = hybrid, linetype = hybrid)) +
  geom_path(size = 1.2) + 
  theme_tufte(base_size = 22) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin =`25%`, xmax = `75%`), height = 0) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1.5),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "black")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Treatment & Season",
                     values = c(
                       `Summer Clean Marine` = "cornflowerblue",
                       `Winter Clean Marine` = "goldenrod3",
                       `Summer All Data` = "cornflowerblue",
                       `Winter All Data` = "goldenrod3"
                     )) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Treatment & Season",
                        values = c(
                          `Summer Clean Marine` = "solid",
                          `Winter Clean Marine` = "dashed",
                          `Summer All Data` = "solid",
                          `Winter All Data` = "dashed")
                        ) +
  xlab("MEK (ppt)") +
  ylab("Altitude (km)")
```

Comment: Similarly, could use `unite("hybrid", c("Meteorological_Season_Factor", "Treatment"), sep = " ") %>%`

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Thank you! I'm still not sure why what I did wasn't working but I'm fairly sure you are right and I somehow messed up the order of the lbaels. Regardless, this is better in this case, because there's no doubt. Thank you.

Comment: You bet! So glad I could help.

Comment: And good luck with your analysis! It looked really interesting.