# Legend title for ggplot with several options

Tags: ggplot2

I am plotting density plots by groups with different colors and linetypes.

```
 ggplot(data = data, 
           aes(x=X, group=G, color=factor(G), linetype = factor(G))) +
           geom_density()
```

How can I change the legend title while keeping it as one legend?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue comes from the fact that when you add a legend title (e.g., using `scale_color_discrete`), you're only doing it for `color` and not `linetype`. The first plot is fine because the legends have identical arguments (i.e., neither is specified). You need to provide identical specifications for each legend in order to combine them. [See this post for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410908/combine-legends-for-color-and-shape-into-a-single-legend).

There may be other ways around this issue, but we can't say for certain since we can't access your dataset (`data`).

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)

# this is ok; one legend
ggplot(data = mtcars, 
       aes(x=mpg, group=cyl, color=factor(cyl), linetype = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_density()

# this is not ok; now two legends
ggplot(data = mtcars, 
       aes(x=mpg, group=cyl, color=factor(cyl), linetype = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_density() + scale_color_discrete("New Name?")

# this is ok again; back to one legend
ggplot(data = mtcars, 
       aes(x=mpg, group=cyl, color=factor(cyl), linetype = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_density() +  
  scale_colour_manual(name = "New!", 
                      labels = c("4", "6", "8"),
                      values = c("red", "blue", "pink")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "New!", 
                        labels = c("4", "6", "8"),
                        values = c(2, 4, 6))
```