# Question about ggplot for multiple variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have following code to plot using different colors and shapes :

```
AUC= c(0.95,0.897,0.595,0.281,0.6872,0.6844,0.9718,0.7748,
       0.807,0.901,0.801,0.982,0.7856,0.7828,0.6748,0.7579
)

roc_alc_lab= c(rep("AUD_Joint_test1",4),rep("AUD_Univariate_test1",4),
               rep("AUD_Joint_test2",4),rep("AUD_Univariate_test2",4)
)



Setting=c("1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4"
          ,"1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4"
)


data_alc_roc=data.frame(Setting,AUC,roc_alc_lab)




p2=data_alc_roc |>
  transform(
    Model = sub("AUD[^_]*_(.*)_.*$", "\\1", roc_alc_lab),
    Test_data = sub(".*_", "", roc_alc_lab)
  ) |>
  
  
  
  ggplot(aes(x = Setting, y = AUC, group = roc_alc_lab)) +
  
  geom_point(aes(color = Test_data ,shape =Model ), size=3 ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(test1 = "blue", test2 = "red")) +
  
  
  labs(color = "Test Data", shape = "Model")
```

Will it be possible to change this code so that "test1" will plot as blue color, where are "test2" will plot as no filled (just the border)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scale_shape_manual` to assign shapes to values. See https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_shape.html for plotting options. In your script, you map `Model` to the shape, and you can then use `scale_shape_manual(values = c(Joint = 16, Univariate = 2))` to assign filled circles to the joint model and open triangles to the univariate model.

```
data_alc_roc |>
  transform(
    Model = sub("AUD[^_]*_(.*)_.*$", "\\1", roc_alc_lab),
    Test_data = sub(".*_", "", roc_alc_lab)
  ) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Setting, y = AUC, group = roc_alc_lab)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Test_data ,shape =Model ), size=3 ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(test1 = "blue", test2 = "red")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(Joint = 16, Univariate = 2)) +
  labs(color = "Test Data", shape = "Model")
```

[image]

**EDIT** in response to "I need a slight different output. That means the circles will be blue filled and red border only. And the triangle would be blue filled and red border only. Would that be possible?"

Does this plot have the assignments that you're interested in? I did this by combining the `Model` and `Test_data` variables as here [Combine legends for color and shape into a single legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410908/combine-legends-for-color-and-shape-into-a-single-legend).

```
data_alc_roc |>
  transform(
    Model = sub("AUD[^_]*_(.*)_.*$", "\\1", roc_alc_lab),
    Test_data = sub(".*_", "", roc_alc_lab)
  ) |>
  transform(
    modelByData = paste(Model,Test_data,sep=", ")
  ) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Setting, y = AUC, group = roc_alc_lab)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = modelByData ,shape = modelByData ), size=3 ) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Model & Data",
                      labels = c("Joint, test1", "Univariate, test1", 
                                 "Joint, test2", "Univariate, test2"),
                      values = c("blue", "red", "blue", "red")) +   
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Model & Data",
                     labels = c("Joint, test1", "Univariate, test1", 
                                "Joint, test2", "Univariate, test2"),
                     values = c(16, 1, 17, 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  But I need a slight different output. That means the circles will be blue filled and red border only. And the triangle would be  blue filled and red border only. Would that be possible?